# Prolog Definite Clause Grammar program for IPv4 address

Tags: prolog, dcg

I'm currently trying to set up a little program for accepting IPv4 dotted quad strings in [SWI Prolog](http://pengines.swi-prolog.org/apps/swish/index.html)  using [DCGs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar) (getting out of the comfort zone during holidays? yes I can!). This is probably going to take me another hour or so, but maybe someone of the readership has one ready already. In which case I can attack [IPv6 address strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Recommended_representation_as_text).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to answer on SWISH, on [this snippet](http://pengines.swi-prolog.org/apps/swish/p/tLjUThyu.pl)

Here is the code, in case the link is volatile...

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).

atom_ipv4(A, IPV4) :- atom_codes(A, Cs), phrase(ipv4(IPV4), Cs).

ipv4(D) -->
    dotted(D).
ipv4(range(D, R)) -->
    dotted(D), "/", integer(R).

dotted(address(A, B, C, D)) -->
    octet(A), ".", octet(B), ".", octet(C), ".", octet(D).

octet(A) --> integer(A), {A < 256}.
```

Note: surely the specification is more complex than that captured by this snippet, since it allows hexadecimal, and more... my purpose what to point out the availability of library(dcg/basics)

Comment: Very nice, even processes subnet notation. This is the answer! I have one which transforms the address into a list characters instead of a list of atoms, and does not do subnet notation and computes the integer value manually: [Snippet](http://pengines.swi-prolog.org/apps/swish/p/tLjUThyu.pl)

Comment: Oh damn I did some manipulation error and scratched your code... can one recover? Apparently not, the help file says "In the future, we will add versioning." ... I am sorry!!

Comment: @false: it's my first test of SWISH. I'll copy here the snippet, but the test itself is more interesting. I don't think those files are temporary, not more than a fiddle... but since they are missing versioning, definitely I'll post the code here

Comment: Consider [this approach](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280078/source-integration-for-external-site) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Answer #2:

```
% Is the atom 'X' a valid IPv4 address?
% Transform the atom 'X' into a list of character codes, which is then processed

is_ipv4(X) :- string_codes(X,Codes), phrase(ipv4, Codes).

% Testing the above

test :- is_ipv4('127.0.0.1'),
    is_ipv4('255.255.255.255'),
    is_ipv4('10.10.10.1'),
    is_ipv4('0010.00010.000.0000'),
    \+is_ipv4('256.0.0.1'),
    \+is_ipv4('12.0.'),
    \+is_ipv4('').


% ----------------------
% Use Definite Clause Grammer to parse a list of character codes
% Subelements can be queried like this: 
% phrase(quadpart, `255`, []).
% phrase(pdigits(X,Y), `123`, []).

ipv4                     --> quadpart, dot, quadpart, dot, quadpart, dot, quadpart.
dot                      --> `.`.
quadpart                 --> pdigits(_,Q), { Q < 256 }.
pdigits(UpPower,UpValue) --> pdigit(Value), !, pdigits(DownPower, DownValue), { UpValue is DownPower*Value+DownValue, UpPower is DownPower*10 }.
pdigits(1,0)             --> [].
pdigit(Value)            --> [D], { code_type(D, digit(Value)) }.
% ---------------------
```